# FineUploader update the parameter

Tags: javascript, c#, web-services, parameter-passing, fine-uploader

How can I update the parameter inside the session, if the uploader already be created at the begin of form load?

```
var galleryUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
  element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-gallery"),
  template: 'qq-template-gallery',
  autoUpload: true,
  deleteFile: {
  enabled: true,
  forceConfirm: true,
  endpoint: "../FileDelete.ashx",
},
session: {
endpoint: "../FilePreload.ashx",
   params: {
   docNo: docNo
  }
},
request: {
    endpoint: "../MultiFileUpload.ashx",
 },
editFilename: { enabled: false }, //params: { // docNo : docNo
//}, thumbnails: { placeholders: { waitingPath: "<%=ResolveUrl("~/images/placeholders/waiting-generic.png")%>", notAvailablePath: "<%=ResolveUrl("~/images/placeholders/not_available-generic.png")%>" } }, validation: { allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'bmp', 'pdf', 'xls', 'xlsx', 'doc', 'docx', 'ppt', 'pptx', 'txt'], sizeLimit: 5120000 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes }, callbacks: { //submitDelete: function (id) {}, //onDelete: function (id) { // data = new FormData(); // data.append("docNo", docNo); // data.append("fileName", this.getName(id)); // DeleteExpFile(formId, data, undefined, undefined, DeleteErrorEvent, DeleteSuccessEvent); // this.cancel(id); //}, //onSubmit: function (id, fileName) {}, //onComplete: function (id, name, responseJSON, maybeXhr) {}, //onSessionRequestComplete: function (responseJSON, success, maybeXhr) {}, } })
```

Comment: How can i update the parameter inside the session, if the uploader already be created ar the first

Comment: Please format your code so others can read easily. Also please edit your question in th original posting + title, not in comment.

Comment: will you have any suggestion for solving the above problem? I spend a lot of time on finding the related reference but still not work